# Dominio de Hosting en Github Pages

Tags: hosting, dominio, github-pages

Estoy intentando conectar mi dominio que compre en Hostinger con mi pagina de GitHub Pages, agradeceria que alguien me ayudara con esto ya vi tutoriales en YouTube pero me sale esto cuando voy a colocar mi dominio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al entrar al dominio aparece la pagina pero no la que tengo en github

Comment: ¿Has visto la documentación que te recomienda el error?

Comment: Es que yo diría que has comprado un hosting para nada, pues comprando tan solo el dominio era suficiente para redireccionarlo a esas páginas (supongo que tocando el DNS para que apunte al servidor de github... eso lo encontrarás en el enlace de la documentación espero)

Comment: Esque solo compre el dominio, Hosting es la pagina en al cual compre el dominio, y lo voy a colocar en github pages me sale el error que coloque ahi

Comment: Es primera vez que hago esto para colocarle un dominio a la pagina, y segui videos de yt que hacen lo que yo hice con los DNS pero no me funciona igualmente

Comment: Vale, ojo con eso, los cambios de los DNS pueden tardar entre minutos o un par de dias en propagarse correctamente, y quizás lo que te está ocurriendo es eso. Pon el nombre de tu dominio [aquí](https://dnschecker.org/) y verifica si ya se han propagado tus cambios.

Comment: Con mayor razón, si es la primera vez que haces algo, ve por la documentación oficial, te ahorrarás tiempo de los videos de youtube que te dirán lo mismo de la documentación.